# PHP fopen bug or wrong in my code

Tags: php

Is this bug from PHP or I do something wrong with my code?

In My PC Windows 7 when I tried to `fopen` file to server `\\192.168.183.5\test\P001.txt` it works, fopen success.

But when I'm in Windows XP and I tried to `fopen` that file to server `\\192.168.183.5\test\P001.txt` it can't work and result errors for this :

```
Warning: fopen(\\192.168.183.5\test\P001.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in...
```

and the source like this :

```
$handle = fopen("\\\\192.168.183.5\\test\\P001.txt", "r");
```

Note: I install XAMPP in each PC.

Please help to review this and give me advice.

Thanks

Comment: Try uploading the file to the server instead.

Comment: If no statement, please help to rate up my post. I need 20 to get in the chat. Maybe there I can get solutions. thanks

Comment: Of course you have checked that the account that's executing the fopen script has appropriate permissions to access files on the remote server

Comment: check if you can access \\192.168.183.5\test\P001.txt from XP too!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the permission for that file.